# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+}\left[\frac{x^{\sin x}-(\sin x)^{x}}{x^3}+\frac{\ln x}{6}\right].$

Tags: calculus, limits

#### Problem

Evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\left[\frac{x^{\sin x}-(\sin x)^{x}}{x^3}+\frac{\ln x}{6}\right].$$

#### Attempt

First, we may obtain
$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\left[\frac{x^{\sin x}-(\sin x)^{x}}{x^3}+\frac{\ln x}{6}\right]=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{6e^{\sin x\ln x}-6e^{x\ln\sin x}+x^3\ln x}{6x^3}.$$
Here, you can apply **L'Hôpital's rule**, but it's too complicated. Moreover, you can also apply **Taylor's formula**, for example
$$e^{\sin x\ln x}=1+\sin x\ln x+\frac{1}{2}(\sin x\ln x)^2+\cdots,\\e^{x\ln\sin x}=1+x\ln\sin x+\frac{1}{2}(x\ln\sin x)^2+\cdots,$$
but you cannot cancel the terms, thus you cannot avoid differentiating, either. Is there any elegant solution?

**P.S.** Please don't suspect the existence of the limit. The result equals $\dfrac{1}{6}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that $x\log \sin x \to 0$ and $\sin x \log x \to 0$ then by Taylor's series we have

- $x^{\sin x}=e^{\sin x \log x}=1+x\log x+\frac12x^2\log^2 x+\frac16x^3\log x(\log^2 x -1)+O(x^4\log^2 x)$
- $(\sin x)^{x}=e^{x \log (\sin x)}=1+x\log x+\frac12x^2\log^2 x+\frac16x^3(\log^3 x -1)+O(x^4\log x)$

then

$$\frac{x^{\sin x}-(\sin x)^{x}}{x^3}+\frac{\ln x}{6}=\frac{\frac16x^3\log^3 x-\frac16x^3\log x-\frac16x^3\log^3 x +\frac16x^3+O(x^4\log x)}{x^3}+\frac{\ln x}{6}=$$

$$=\frac16+O(x\log x) \to \frac16$$

---

To see how obtain the Taylor's expansion, let consider the first one, then since

- $\sin x =x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5) \implies \sin x \log x=x\log x-\frac16 x^3\log x+O(x^5\log x)$
- $e^t = 1+t+\frac12 t^2+\frac16t^3+O(t^4)$

we obtain that

$$x^{\sin x}=e^{\sin x \log x}
=1+\left(x\log x-\frac16 x^3\log x+O(x^5\log x)\right)+\frac12\left(x\log x-\frac16 x^3\log x+O(x^5\log x)\right)^2+\frac16\left(x\log x-\frac16 x^3\log x+O(x^5\log x)\right)^3+O(x^5\log^4 x)=$$

$$=1+x\log x-\frac16 x^3\log x+\frac12x^2\log^2x-\frac16x^4\log^2x+\frac16x^3\log^3x+O(x^4\log^2x)=$$

$$=1+x\log x+\frac12x^2\log^2x+\frac16x^3\log x(\log^2x-1)+O(x^4\log^2x)$$

and for the second one since

- $\log (1+t)= t-\frac12t^2+\frac13t^3+O(t^4)$
- $\sin x =x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5)\implies \frac{\sin x}x=1-\frac16 x^2+O(x^4)$
- $\log \sin x=\log x+\log \frac{\sin x}x=\log x+\log \left(1-\frac16 x^2+O(x^4)\right)=\log x-\frac16 x^2+O(x^4)$
- $x\log \sin x=x\log x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5)$

we obtain that

$$(\sin x)^x=e^{x\log \sin x}=1+\left(x\log x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5)\right)+\frac12\left(x\log x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5)\right)^2+\frac16\left(x\log x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5)\right)^3+O(x^4\log^4x)$$

$$=1+x\log x-\frac16 x^3+\frac12x^2\log^2x-\frac16x^4\log x+\frac16x^3\log^3 x+O(x^4\log x)=$$

$$=1+x\log x+\frac12x^2\log^2x+\frac16x^3(\log^3 x-1)+O(x^4\log x)$$

Comment: How to derive Taylor‘s Formula in such form？

Comment: $$e^{\sin x\ln x}=1+\sin x\ln x+\frac{1}{2}(\sin x\ln x)^2+\cdots,$$

Comment: @mengdie1982 Starting form $x^{\sin x}=e^{\sin x \log x}$ and then expanding then $\sin x \log x$ and then using that $x^a \log x \to 0$ for any $a>0$ to expand the exponential. It is not a short way but it is not difficult,

Comment: Put $\sin x=1+\cdots$ into it?

Comment: @mengdie1982 Yes that's also good but I would prefer at frst expand sin x log x and then the exponential.

Comment: @mengdie1982 We have $\sin x = x -x^3/6+O(x^4)$.

Comment: @mengdie1982 I've added the full derivation for the series expansion.

Comment: @ gimusi Thanks a lot. But could you explain in details that how "the big $O$" operates in your computation?

Comment: @mengdie1982 Are you aware about big-O notation? Do you prefer little-o notation? Please explain better what is your doubt about that.

Comment: For example, in your expansion of $x^{\sin x}$, why the former $O(x^5\ln x)$ changes into $O(x^4\ln^2 x)$ in the result.

Comment: @mengdie1982 My question is: have you some specific doubt for that application of big-O notation or your doubt on it is more general?

Comment: @mengdie1982 That's a good question. When we start we are not always sure to which oreder we need to expand the series. Here we see soon that a third order suffices then we don't need to keep the $O(x^5\log x) $term which is included into the final $O(x^4\ln^2x)$.

Comment: I know the meaning of the notation. But I am not sure how to make operation about the notation.

Comment: @mengdie1982 For the same reason in the final computation the $O(x^4\log^2 x)$ term is "adsorbed by $O(x^4\log x)$ term.

Comment: @mengdie1982 If you refer to the definition we have that $$O(x^4\log^2x)+O(x^5\log x)=O(x^4\log^2x)$$

Comment: But I think $O(x^4\ln x)$ is enough.... For the reason that $\frac{O(x^4\ln x)}{x^3}=\frac{O(x^4\ln x)}{x^4\ln x}\cdot x\ln x \to 0(x \to 0+)$, which is a product of a bounded variable and an infinitesimal.

Comment: @mengdie1982 Yes at the end all is included in that term but when we consider the single expansions it is better to keep the maximum order term and only in the final step keep what we need to evaluate the limit.

Comment: Thanks very much. you teach me a lot.

Comment: @mengdie1982 It is a usual way to proceed, at first we need to expand keeping some more term and when we are sure which terms are important we can fix the steps and keep only these terms. For simpler limit we can guess easily which terms we need to keep for that one it is more difficult to guess at first. The rule is: one term more do not lead to error but one term less could lead to a mistake.

Comment: @mengdie1982 You are welcome! You only need to practice with that to become more confident! Anyway your knowledge seems alredy very good up to now. Bye

Answer (score 3):

The key here is obtaining the expansions for $x^{\sin x} $ and $\sin^xx$ but it is simpler to deal with their logarithms. Consider
\begin{align} 
f(x) &=\sin x \log x-x\log\sin x\notag\\
&=(x\log x)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\dots \right)-x\log x-x\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\dots\right)\notag\\
&=\notag\\
&=-\frac{x^3\log x} {6}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\notag
\end{align}
And then the expression under limit is $$\sin^xx\cdot\frac{e^{f(x)} - 1}{x^3}+\frac{\log x} {6}$$ which can be further written as $$\sin^xx \left(\frac{e^{f(x)} - 1}{x^3}+\frac{\log x} {6}\right) +\frac{\log x} {6}\cdot(1-\sin^xx) $$ From the expansion of $f(x) $ it is clear that $f(x) =o(x^2)$ and hence $$\frac{e^{f(x)} - 1}{x^3}=-\frac{\log x} {6}+\frac{1}{6}+o(1)$$ The desired limit is $1/6$ if we can prove that $\sin^xx \to 1$ and $(\log x) (1-\sin^xx) \to 0$ and this is not difficult to prove.

We just need to note that $$(\log x) \cdot(1-\sin^xx)=-\frac{\exp(x\log\sin x) - 1}{x\log\sin x} \cdot x\log \sin x\cdot\log x$$ and the fraction above tends to $1$ so that the limit of above expression is equal to the limit of $$-x\log x\left(\log x+\log\frac{\sin x} {x} \right) $$ which is same as $$-x(\log x) ^2-(x\log x) \log\frac{\sin x} {x} $$ and the above clearly tends to $0$.